# How to create own dataset for Mask RCNN?

Tags: dataset

I have two folders of images, one includes images and another includes bitmaps as annotations.How can I prepare them as dataset for use in Mask RCNN?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for - a JSON list of file paths? file contents expressed as JSON data? You might want to review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise this.

Answer (score 0):

For Mask RCNN you need to directly annotate the images so that it could be lablled also in a specific class. Use tools such as VGG Annotator for this purpose. Then you have to customly edit the .py file for your requiremtns and run it, here you will be the directory of these images along with the annotations so that it can recognise what part of the image is representing which class. Later you need to train it these using a pretrained weight file of COCO dataset. This will generate your custom weight file. THis custom weight is used for testing.

Refer these for more insight

https://github.com/gabrielgarza/Mask_RCNN

https://github.com/d-smit/kangaroo-detection-mask-rcnn

https://github.com/thomasjvarghese799/Mask-RCNN-on-Rick-Morty